"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" in GitHub Actions
I'm trying to build a workflow that would pull React code from GitHub repo and upload it on the Azure web app, however, I'm getting an error:

Below is the workflow code:
ERROR: Syntax Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: build/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'rectifycreditclient'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_E194E92742C24133961AB59ECD48DA31 }}
          package:

Ideally it should push the GitHub code into Azure web app.

Have you considered using actions that aren't substantially out of date?

@devTeamMonconnect, Please share your code or GitHub repo if possible.

@jonrsharpe, i have tried but it;s not working.

@PravallikaKV, this is private repo which was created for react which has only hello world app basic out of the box.

Why show the out of date versions, then? Give a [mre] that's likely to work, at least.

@devTeamMonconnect, Check if the below solution helps to fix the issue.

I got the same error when I tried to deploy the react app with  axios using GitHub actions.
To resolve this error, add the below code in package.json.

Thanks @AyoubXwire for the code:

"jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!axios)/"]
},

My Package.json:
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!axios)/"]
},
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}


Able to deploy the app without using GitHub actions:



